# Is the autocovariance of a random walk with drift same as that of without drift?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes

A random walk without drift is not stationary. Because its autocovariance function depends on time. A random walk with drift is not stationary as its mean is not constant.
But what is the autocovariance of a random walk with drift? Is it the same as that of a random walk with no drift?

Comment: You can obtain the expression of the autocovariance function. Start writing the equation of each process recursively: for the random walk:
$y_t=\underbrace{y_{t-1}}_{y_{t-2}+\varepsilon_{t-1}}+\varepsilon_t\to$ 
$y_t=y_0+\sum_{i=1}^t\varepsilon_i$; for the r.w. with drift:
$z_t=\underbrace{\alpha+z_{t-1}}_{\alpha+z_{t-2}+\varepsilon_{t-1}}+\varepsilon_t\to$ $z_t=z_0 + \alpha t + \sum_{i=1}^t\varepsilon_i$. You can assume that the process starts at a fixed value, e.g., $y_0=z_0=0$. Upon these expressions you can obtain the mean and the autocovariances.

Comment: Related posts: [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181167/)
and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140836/).